# count frequency of all sword in whole corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, word-frequency

I am trying to count how many times each word appear in whole corpus.

But i am getting the error :

```
 corpus_root = os.path.abspath('../nlp_urdu/out1_data')
    mycorpus = nltk.corpus.reader.TaggedCorpusReader(corpus_root,'.*')
    noun=[]
    count_freq = defaultdict(int)
    for infile in (mycorpus.fileids()):
        print(infile)
    for i in (mycorpus.tagged_sents()):
         texts = [word for word, pos in i  if (pos == 'NN' )]
         noun.append(texts)  
         count_freq[noun]+= 1
         print(count_freq)
```

error which i am getting is :

> count_freq[noun]+= 1
>
> `TypeError`: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: If you're mining text, you should look at a CountVectorizer or TFIDF.

Answer (score 0):

`texts` is a list of `noun`

`count_freq` is a dict with each key must must a `noun` (a `string`)

```
corpus_root = os.path.abspath('../nlp_urdu/out1_data')
    mycorpus = nltk.corpus.reader.TaggedCorpusReader(corpus_root,'.*')
    count_freq = defaultdict(int)
    for infile in (mycorpus.fileids()):
        print(infile)
    for i in (mycorpus.tagged_sents()):
         texts = [word for word, pos in i  if (pos == 'NN' )]
         for noun in texts :             
             count_freq[noun]+= 1

    print(count_freq)
```

Comment: actually i just used words which are noun  and those words are in "texts"and then appended  the whole nouns from the corpus in  in list named as noun.

Comment: this is not showing the correct output.there are 13000 nouns.it is just repeating the one file